# (android) ImageView gets bigger when i set background

Tags: android

When "btn_report_addImage1" is clicked, the app call camera function to take a picture.  then, the button is gone and the inner relativeLayout is appeared to show the picture i took and to show remove button on the top-right side of the picture.

The problem is:
I set the size of the image view with 65dp for width and height. 
But when the picture is shown on the imageView, the picture gets bigger than before.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_report_addImage1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_report_image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_report_image1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_report_removeImage1"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textSize="5dp"
                  />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_report_addImage2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_report_image2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_report_image2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_report_removeImage2"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the scaleType as fitXY. That's the reason. `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 0):

Scaling Image to fit the view in both the Axis we call `fitXY`, in your case you have already defined the `l*b` of Image, So remove the `ScaleType = fitXY`:

```
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_report_image1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                // scaleType removed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set ImageView scaleType 'centerCrop'.

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_report_image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add image pragmatically in src. so you can get image size proper and display proper.